# How to bind ListView in asp.net from multiple tables?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am using ASP.NET to create a website. In one of the .aspx pages, I display the some properties of a given data model -

```
<asp:ListView ID="bidList" runat="server" 
            DataKeyNames="BidID" GroupItemCount="8"
            ItemType="talker.Models.Model1" SelectMethod="GetCategoryBids">
```

Where Model1 is the name of one of the tables I created and it looks like this -

```
public class Model1
  {
  [key]
  public int Model1Id {get; set; }
  public string ProvidingUserName {get; set;}
  public User AppUser { get; set; }
  public int? UserId { get; set; }
 }
```

And the User class looks like this -

```
 public class User{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName {get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
 }
```

Now, I am able to display the user name because it is a field in Model1. However, I now want to display the FName field from the User class based on the UserName (which is unique). I'm not sure how to do this though. I could just carry FName (and other information from User) in Model1 itself, but then that would involve carrying around a lot of unnecessary information. Would the site speed be significantly faster if the Users table was to become large and I just carried all the fields in the Model1 table?

Comment: Can you show the query already written for this ?

Comment: So far, I didn't have to write any query. I am simply able to show the fields from Model1 using for example -
      <%#:Item.ProvidingUserName%>. I now want to add       <%#:Item.User.FName%> but this of course won't work as .NET doesn't know which user it should use.

Comment: Why do you say <%#:Item.AppUser.FName%> would not work ? If you have the data already in memory no need to denormalize the model. Just bind to Item.AppUser.FName and it is done. If AppUser is not filled yet it is more a problem how to retrieve the data and not now to visualize in asp.net.